# UI Component date display wrong in magento2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

When i updating date using inline edit in magento2:

**Actual date:**
[image]

**Db Save:**
[image]

**Grid Display After Save:**
[image]

why it display one prev date? How can i resolve it?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this one?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

add date Format

```
<column name="run_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Run Time</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

1. Now delete the records that you find from a ui_bookmark table.
2. Clear the cache

see more: https://www.screencast.com/t/qePBLRpe27

Comment: I have tried but  Not working

Comment: @RutveeSojitra can you please check Answer is updated

Comment: still same issue facing

Answer (score 0):

Have you found the solution yet?
Try change timezone and check again
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `<item name="timezone" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>` to the date column. In my case it seems to have fixed the issue.

```
<column name="start_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Event Start Date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
        **<item name="timezone" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>**
    </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```